# NSPredicate wildcard in attribute name

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

Is there a way to include wildcards in the attribute name of an NSPredicate?

For example, I have a predicate like this:

```
keyPath CONTAINS 'C1b'
```

I use this predicate on an array of dictionaries. In the dictionaries, `keyPath` looks something like this:

```
A2a1*;B1a*;C1*;D4*
```

Using the above predicate on this `keyPath` value, it doesn't come up as a match. If I change `C1b` to just `C1` then it does come up as a match. How can I make it work with the wildcard character?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear or if there's more information that I can provide.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that I need to match each section of `keyPath`. So, for example, my predicate would look something like this:

```
(keyPath CONTAINS 'B1a') AND (keyPath CONTAINS 'C1c1') AND (keyPath CONTAINS 'A2a1') AND (keyPath CONTAINS 'D4a')
```

Comment: I think you want to use LIKE instead of CONTAINS if you're using wildcards.

Comment: When using `LIKE`, `C1` won't even work. I think it's because I have `A2a1*;B1a*;C1*;D4*` instead of something like just `C1*`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works correctly

The patternString can contain the wildcards

eg, patternString = A2a1*

```
-(NSMutableArray *)searchByPattern:(NSString *)patternString inputArray:(NSMutableArray *)inputArray
{
    NSLog(@"orginal Array count=%d",[inputArray count]);
    NSString *match=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",patternString];
    NSLog(@"match = %@",match);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like %@",match];    
    NSMutableArray *mArrayFiltered = [[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
    //NSLog(@"mArrayFiltered = %@ count = %d",mArrayFiltered,[mArrayFiltered count]);
    return mArrayFiltered;
}
```

Comment: That only works if my pattern string is `A2a1*` and not `A2a1*;B1a*;C1*;D4*`.

Comment: You mean that "A2a1*;B1a*;C1*;D4*" as a single patternString? - If is a single string you need to remove ";" from it, then it will work perfectly

Comment: Still not working. I guess I should have given a little more information. See the edit on my question. Using `LIKE` there gives me the same problem, even if I replace the `;` with a space.

Comment: Did you integrate successfully?